# I am changing my img src in setTimeout and although my source is changing correctly, my image is not changing. what am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, css, settimeout

I am changing my img src in setTimeout and although my source is changing correctly, my image is not changing. what am i doing wrong?

```js
var paths = ['img/img1.jpg', 'img/img2.jpg'];

var img = document.getElementById('imgg');
var i = 0;
var timer = setInterval(function () {
    // If we've reached the end of the array...
    if (i >= paths.length) {
        i = 0;
    }

    //console.log(paths[i]);
    img.src = paths[i];
    console.log(img.src);
    i = i + 1; // Sete the path to the current counter and then increase the counter
}, 10000);
```

My HTML code is

```html
<a href="#" style="object-fit: contain;"class="image profilepic"><img id="imgg" src="img/img1.jpg" alt="image" data-position="center center" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to give an address, be sure to enter ./

```html
<a href="#" style="object-fit: contain" class="image profilepic"
  ><img id="imgg" src="./img/img1.jpg" alt="image" data-position="center center"
/></a>
<script>
  var paths = ["./img/img1.jpg", "./img/img2.jpg"];

  var img = document.getElementById("imgg");
  var i = 0;
  var timer = setInterval(function () {
    // If we've reached the end of the array...
    if (i >= paths.length) {
      i = 0;
    }

    console.log(paths[i]);
    img.src = paths[i];
    console.log(img.src);
    i = i + 1; // Sete the path to the current counter and then increase the counter
  }, 10000);
</script>
```